# How to Extract value from json Array

Tags: java, json

I am Calling a Api Which is returning me this Response

```
[
    {
        "message": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "Msg1,Msg2,Msg3,Msg4",
            "valueInfo": {}
        },
        "Decision": {
            "type": "Boolean",
            "value": false,
            "valueInfo": {}
        }
    },
    {
        "message": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "[Msg2, Msg3,Msg5]",
            "valueInfo": {}
        },
        "Decision": {
            "type": "Boolean",
            "value": false,
            "valueInfo": {}
        }
    }
]
```

Now I have to Extract Message and Decision from response one by one How I can Do This. 
Not Down there could be Multiple Messages in an Object.

Comment: read Working with JSON https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: Which programming language or framework do you use ?

Comment: @HaktanEnesBiçer Java

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i can access Array of objects Easily but i don't know how Access  multiple values of msg

Comment: @Ruzihm can you please suggest me what more information should i add in this question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
String res = "[\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "        \"message\": {\n" +
        "            \"type\": \"String\",\n" +
        "            \"value\": \"Msg1,Msg2,Msg3,Msg4\",\n" +
        "            \"valueInfo\": {}\n" +
        "        },\n" +
        "        \"Decision\": {\n" +
        "            \"type\": \"Boolean\",\n" +
        "            \"value\": false,\n" +
        "            \"valueInfo\": {}\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "        \"message\": {\n" +
        "            \"type\": \"String\",\n" +
        "            \"value\": \"[Msg2, Msg3,Msg5]\",\n" +
        "            \"valueInfo\": {}\n" +
        "        },\n" +
        "        \"Decision\": {\n" +
        "            \"type\": \"Boolean\",\n" +
        "            \"value\": false,\n" +
        "            \"valueInfo\": {}\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "]";

try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(res);

    JSONObject[] messages = new JSONObject[jsonArray.length()];
    JSONObject[] Decision = new JSONObject[jsonArray.length()];


    for(int i =0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
        messages[i] = ((JSONObject) (jsonArray.get(i))).getJSONObject("message");
        Decision[i] = ((JSONObject) (jsonArray.get(i))).getJSONObject("Decision");


    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of `value` in `message` is not sure. Sometimes it is `xxx,xxx,xxx`, sometimes it is `[xxx,xxx,xxx]`. So you may need this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "[\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"message\": {\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"String\",\n" +
            "            \"value\": \"Msg1,Msg2,Msg3,Msg4\",\n" +
            "            \"valueInfo\": {}\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"Decision\": {\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"Boolean\",\n" +
            "            \"value\": false,\n" +
            "            \"valueInfo\": {}\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"message\": {\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"String\",\n" +
            "            \"value\": \"[Msg2, Msg3,Msg5]\",\n" +
            "            \"valueInfo\": {}\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"Decision\": {\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"Boolean\",\n" +
            "            \"value\": false,\n" +
            "            \"valueInfo\": {}\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "]";


    List<MessageDecision> list = new Gson().fromJson(json,
            new TypeToken<List<MessageDecision>>(){}.getType());

    for (MessageDecision data: list){
        System.out.println(data.message.getValueList());
    }

}

class MessageDecision {
    public Message message;
    public Decision Decision;

    class Message {
        String type;
        String value;

        //
        List<String> valueList;


        public List<String> getValueList() {
            if (type.equals("String")) {
                if (value!=null) {
                    if (value.startsWith("[")) {

                        valueList = new Gson().fromJson(value, new TypeToken<List<String>>() {
                        }.getType());
                    } else {
                        String tempValues[] = value.split(",");
                        valueList = Arrays.asList(tempValues);
                    }
                }
                return valueList;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    class Decision {
        String type;
        Object value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to jquery and need message in an independent array to work with,

`$(a).map(function (i, item) {return {item.message.value}).get();`